# Find the harmonic conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

> $$u(x,y)=x^3+ax^2y+bxy^2+2y^3$$
>   Be a harmonic function and $v(x,y)$ be its harmonic conjugate .If $v(0,0)=1$ then find the
>
> $$|a+b+v(1,1)|$$

The solution i tried-since $u$ is harmonic so by laplace equation we get
$$6x+2ay+2bx+12y=0$$
By comparing coefficients we get $a=-6 $ and $b=-3$ so we get 
$$u(x,y)=x^3-6x^2y-3xy^2+2y^3$$

Next i am not getting how to proceed please give me a hint

Thankyou.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $6x+2ay+2bx+4=0$?

Comment: Hint would be to look at e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate especially the example there.

Comment: @Prototank sorry for my typo.

Comment: @WhatsUp insted of $C$ in wikipidia they should write $f(y)$?

Comment: *A priori* it's $f(y)$ if you only look at $\partial v/\partial x$, but if you also take into account $\partial v/\partial y$, then you'll see that $f(y)$ is indeed independent of $y$, so it becomes a $C$.

Answer (score 1):

$$u(x,y) =x^3 -6x^2 y -3xy^2 +2y^3 =(x^3 -3xy^2 ) +2 (y^3 -3x^2 y) =Re( (x+iy)^3 ) - Im(2 (x+iy)^3 )= Re z^3 -2Im z^3 == Re [(1-2i)z^3 ]$$
Hence the conjugate is equal to

$$v(x,y)=Im [(1-2i) z^3 ]$$

$$|a+b +v(1,1) |=|-9 +Im [(1-2i) (1+i)^3]|=|-9 +6|=3$$

Answer (score 1):

You find $a,b$ due to $u$ harmonicity. Now by Cauchy-Riemann Equation:
$$\begin{array}{c}
v & = & \int \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} dx & = & \int -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} dx & = & \int (6x^2+{\color{white} 1}6xy-6y^2) dx & = & 2x^3+3x^2y-6xy^2+C_y \\
v & = & \int \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} dy & = & \int +\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dy & = & \int (3x^2-12xy-3y^2) dy & = & 3x^2y-6xy^2-y^3+C_x \\
\end{array}$$
So $v$ is as follows:
$$v = 2x^3+3x^2y-6xy^2-y^3+C$$
Now by initial value:
$$1 = v(0,0) = C \Longrightarrow C=1 \Longrightarrow v(x,y) = 2x^3+3x^2y-6xy^2-y^3+1 \Longrightarrow v(1,1) = -1 \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow |a+b+v(1,1)|=|-6-3-1|=+10$$